# Blinking Monty Hall solution

Tags: bayes-theorem, monty-hall

http://allendowney.blogspot.com/2011/10/blinky-monty-problem.html

If we let the prior state be $P(A)=1/3,P(C)=2/3$ and the evidence be the blinking, isn't $$P(E)=P(E|A)P(A)+P(E|C)P(C)=3/5*1/3+3/13*2/3=23/65$$ so $$P(A|E)=\frac{P(E|A)P(A)}{P(E)}=\frac{3/5*1/3}{23/65}=13/23=0.565$$?

But apparently this is wrong because the website says $P(A|E)=0.51$.

BTW I did change the evidence from the webpage to exclude the choosing of door B, but conditioned everything to reflect that so I don't see why it shouldn't give the same answer.

Comment: P(E|A) = 3/13 not 3/5 and P(E|C) = 3/5 not 3/13.

Comment: @fleablood but A is the event of choosing the correct door, and prob of blinking given the correct door was chosen is 3/5

Comment: Oops.  You are right.

Comment: He has a 3/5 chance of blinking when I pick the correct door. And that would make the answer 5/23

Comment: P(C) should be 1/3 here, but that still doesn't make the answer 0.51.

Comment: If you condition everything on the posterior of original Monty Hall I think P(A)=1/3 and P(C)=2/3

Comment: Ah yeah I didn't see that you conditioned on the posterior, I agree with your above probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the evidence $E$ is that he opens door B *and* blinks. Assuming they are independent, $$P(E|A)=P(\text{opens door B}|A)P(\text{blinks}|A)=\frac12\times\frac35=\frac3{10}$$
This is where your calculation was incorrect.

EDIT:

Actually, I should have continued with the calcuation.

$$P(E|A)=P(\text{opens door B and blinks}|\text{car behind A})=\frac35\frac12=\frac3{10}\\P(E|C)=P(\text{opens door B and blinks}|\text{car behind C})=\frac3{13}\frac11=\frac3{13}\\P(A|E)=\frac{\frac3{10}\frac13}{\frac3{10}\frac13+\frac3{13}\frac23}=\frac{13}{23}=0.565...$$
which is exactly as you got.

So it appears your link indeed has it wrong.

Comment: How does that give 0.51? And shouldn't it not matter if we relabel the doors?

Comment: But P(E|blinks) is 3/10.  So the OP took that into account.

Comment: @Akababa yes you're right, it turns out this gives the same answer (see edit)